# How can I get /usr/bin/time to recognize my R environment?

Tags: r, bash, time, rscript

I am trying to measure the peak memory usage of an R script using /usr/bin/time. The following code works fine:

```
Rscript testMemoryUsage.R
```

as does:

```
time Rscript testMemoryUsage.R
```

However, the following doesn't work:

```
/usr/bin/time Rscript testMemoryUsage.R
```

The error is due to packages not being found:

"Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages -> withCallingHandlers -> library
Execution halted
Command exited with non-zero status 1"

I realize there is not much reproducible code but at a conceptually level, why does the shell built in time command work here but not the executable /usr/bin/time? How can I get /usr/bin/time to use the same R environment where the packages are installed? Thank you.

Comment: Is `Rscript` wrapped by an alias? A shell function? We need to know how it's implemented before we can say how to fix this. Run `type Rscript` (assuming your shell really is bash) and [edit] the output into the question.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense unless you set some things in your per-user dotfiles that are not invoked via `/usr/bin/time`.  Witness:

```bash
$ Rscript -e 'length(Sys.getenv())'
[1] 67
$ time Rscript -e 'length(Sys.getenv())'
[1] 67

real    0m0.355s
user    0m0.289s
sys     0m0.062s
$ /usr/bin/time Rscript -e 'length(Sys.getenv())'
[1] 67
0.31user 0.07system 0:00.39elapsed 98%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 65044maxresident)k
0inputs+8outputs (0major+17430minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$
```

I used the number of environment variables R knows as a test here, you could equally do

```
$ Rscript -e 'print(.libPaths())'
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library" 
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"           
$
```

to drill down where/how the setups differ for you.  But in short it *has* to be with how you control how R runs / is set up for you.